# How to scroll inside an element python selenium

Tags: python, selenium

So I'm trying to scrape data from in an element within a website, but I'm getting blank items inside the array which I believe would be fixed by scrolling inside the element (not the entire website). How would you do this? I want it to scroll by something like 10 pixels after it gets each data value.

Here's the code:

```py
while True:
    try:
        ep_data(data_questions, data_answers, question_and_answer_number)
        question_and_answer_number += 1
        
   except:
        break
```

(The x-path for the scroll bar of the element is `//*[@id="preview-grid-container"]/div[2]`)

Answer (score 0):

You can use execute script, something like this.

```
ele = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id="preview-grid-container"]/div[2]")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", ele)
```

Comment: Thanks for that, it works. But is there any way to use scrollBy as I want to only scroll a certain amount in a loop

Comment: put this into the loop and iterate for each element.